# Git bash shows me the ed25519 key instead of the rsa key fingerprint

Tags: github, rsa, ed25519

I tried a tutorial to set up GitHub SSH key, but when I type in the prompt it shows me the ed25519 instead of the rsa keyfingerprint.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUxUj.jpg]

Any pointer on how to add the rsa key fingerprint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> ED25519 key fingerprint is...
> ```

This is not related to your `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` key pair.

It is related to the remote host (`github.com`) has its own key, whose fingerprint you must accept, updating your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.
As [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760278/6309):

> The reason you're seeing an ECDSA key being offered is that OpenSSH prefers ECDSA over Ed25519 keys.
> This is less a comment on the security, as most folks agree that Ed25519 keys are just as secure (or more) as 256-bit ECDSA keys, and more for backwards compatibility.
> When OpenSSH added Ed25519 keys, if they had been prioritized over ECDSA keys, then a changed host key error would show up when logging in the next time.

You can see those fingerprints in "[GitHub’s SSH host keys are now published in the API](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-18-githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/)"

Simply answer 'yes' to the 'authenticity' question, and *then* your key will be used to establish a connection.

Comment: Tried it and also deleted the rsa files and every time I make a new key it gives me the ed25519

Comment: @pclearn  OK. I have rewritten the answer to address the actual root cause. If you see a question in your prompt, answer 'yes'.

Comment: Worked to add the key to register to github

Comment: @pclearn Great! Well done.